# Can't request data from div after ajax call. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

This example works well and the same I use on my project, but the data I use, in this case the div with the `data-name` attr is loaded by ajax and it looks like it doesn't work.
In the console, firefox output this after the `click`:

> getPreventDefault() sollte nicht mehr verwendet werden. Verwenden Sie stattdessen defaultPrevented.jquery.min...

http://jsfiddle.net/n495c/14/

js

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content div").click(function() {
            var title = $(this).data("name");
            $("#content div").text(title);
        });
    });
```

html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div data-name="Neu"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#content div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: The message `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` is actually from jQuery, they are using a deprecated method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegated event handler :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#content div', function() {
        var title = $(this).data("name");
        $("#content div").text(title);
    });
});
```